# Access ListView in xaml from different .cs files?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to access a ListView object in a XAML file from a non-bindable `.cs` file.

I have a XAML file called "TabPage1" where I have a grid layout and that is where my listview is located. https://gyazo.com/1a4d8635ffcb5acdd291bc8f92caae88

However, I am receiving shared data from share option in android through an "activity" .cs file called "RecieveDataFromApp, this is where I handle the incoming data. (shown in the picture above on the left side)

From this .cs file (RecieveDataFromApp) I want to pass in incoming data to this ListView that is located in a xaml file which is not bound to my "RecieveDataFromApp.cs" file.

https://gyazo.com/80fff3df19e19e5dbb1c5bc8e6f54995 if you check at line 35, this is where I want to access the ListView that is in TabPage1.xaml.

Comment: do NOT post code as images.  Take the time to copy and format your code so its readable.  I'd suggest reading up on MessagingCenter as way to pass data

Comment: Oh okay sorry , thought it would be better so that ppl could see how the 2 different type of files are placed in the project as they are not in the same root level or what to say!

Comment: I looked up on MessaginCenter but it doesn't seem to work passing from root level "Revamp.Android" to Revamp

Comment: So now, when you know you shouldn't post images, please [edit] your question and include the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use DependencyService  to have values from Android project into shared project

**Create Interface in shared project let call it IGetSmth**

```
 public interface IGetSmth
{
    string smth { get; }

}
```

**In you android project create class named GetSmth**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(GetSmth))]
public class Getsmth : IGetSmth
{
    public string smth
    {
        get { return ReceiveDataFromApp.SomeTextInMainActivity; }
    }
}
```

**Finaly** in you ReceiveDataFromApp activity create `SomeTextInMainActivity` property
`public static string SomeTextInMainActivity { get; set; }`
and don't forget to give it a value in you code and you can get it in shared project 
 `string SomeTextFromAndroidProject = DependencyService.Get<IGetSmth>().smth;`
You can find sample [here](https://github.com/h0s/passingdatatoshared)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for reply so far! When i do string Kappa = DependencyService.Get<IGetSmth>().smth; the program returns "object refrence not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: public static string smth = "nick"; is the variable i am passing thrrough the class and interface

Comment: i forget to mention you need to register the dependency -
`[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(IGetSmth))]`

Comment: Oh okay! i got a different error this time toh. "Default constructor notr found for type Project.IGetSmth. https://gyazo.com/192c5a154ee9ff06835518a2c7d82a89   The error is on this line still "string Kappa = DependencyService.Get<IGetSmth>().smth;

Comment: you named it `DataText` instead of `smth` !

Comment: ye well smth = DataText in this case, Renamed it for my own sake : )

Comment: so wherever smth is suppose to be, DataText is there

Comment: so to try u need `string SomeTextFromAndroidProject = DependencyService.Get<IGetSmth>().DataText; `

Comment: Yes and that is what i have here                                                       "string Kappa = DependencyService.Get<IGetSmth>().DataText;" but this gives error saying "Default constructor not found for type Project.IGetSmth"

Comment: where did you add `[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(IGetSmth))]`

Comment: https://gyazo.com/26cf837a6ab6b50dd4dc4a353f614de4 in the AssemblyInfo.cs file under project.android

Comment: i think that u must add it in GetSmth file in android project

Comment: This is the error i am getting from where i set a string to the value of "DependencyService.Get<IGetSmth>(),DataText;" https://gyazo.com/df2984ab5d47727426ac048042a5d08b   ; and this the constructor in IGetSmth https://gyazo.com/4827bd660ed8fe57e126d68275c8fd3e

Comment: Sorry i was mistaking the registration of dependency should be in shared project in tabpage

Comment: I am not totaly sure on what you mean by "registartion of dependency should be in shared project in tabpage". I guess this is the registration? "            string Kappa = DependencyService.Get<IGetData>().DataText;
" and that is what i have in tabpage1

Comment: you will find here a sample project i created for you tested and work fine . https://github.com/h0s/passingdatatoshared

Comment: i add a sample project that you work you can test on it and know how it work

Comment: Yep that works great! got it to work now!.Really great help from you :), made you the answer